# How do I get the value of collection.find(connect.data).fetch()?

Tags: rest, api, http, meteor

I am trying to create a meteor [RESTful API](https://themeteorchef.com/tutorials/writing-an-api) for my app based on this [The Meteor Chef](https://themeteorchef.com/tutorials/writing-an-api) online tutorial. The HTTP package is installed in the beginning of the tutorial, in order to test the RESTful API once the API development is completed.

I am currently in the testing phase and cant seem to get my `GET Methods` used to retrieve data from my collection to work.

Find below my GET Method code:

```
methods: {
   pescrow: {
     GET: function( context, connection ) {

    var hasQuery = API.utility.hasData( connection.data );
    console.log("hasQuery value == " +hasQuery+ " on line 183");

      if ( hasQuery ) {
        connection.data.owner = connection.owner;
        console.log("Your in GET::hasQuery: Line 187 " + connection.data );

        var getPescrows = recipientsDetails.find( connection.data ).fetch();             
        console.log("getPescrows value: " +getPescrows+ " Line 203");


      if ( getPescrows.length > 0 ) {
        // We found some pescrows, we can pass a 200 (success) and return the
        // found pescrows.
        console.log("getPescrows found Line 205");
        API.utility.response( context, 200, getPescrows );
        } 
        else {
        console.log("getPescrows NOT found Line 208!");
        // Bummer, we didn't find any pescrows. We can pass a 404 (not found)
        // and return an error message.
        API.utility.response( context, 404, { error: 404, message: "No Pescrows found, dude." } );
        }
        } 
        else {
      // Our request didn't contain any params, so we'll just return all of
      // the pescrows we have for the owner associated with the passed API key.
        var getPescrows = recipientsDetails.find( { "owner": connection.owner } ).fetch();
        API.utility.response( context, 200, getPescrows );
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I test my API via the Chrome console by pasting in the below code:

```
HTTP.get( "http://localhost:8000/paymentC2B/v1", { 
params: { 
"api_key": "b21d83ef267bd829a9d732551270c718",
"paymentStatus": "Pending",                                                                      
"recipientNumber" : "0705087633"
 } 
 }, function( error, response ) {
 if ( error ) {
 console.log( error );
 } else {
 console.log( response );
 }
 });
```

And the response I get in the terminal is:

```
hasQuery == true Line 183
Your in GET::hasQuery: Line 187 [object Object]
getPescrows value:  Line 203
getPescrows NOT found Line 208!
```

When I run the query below in the console it successfully yields:

```
    recipientsDetails.find({paymentStatus:"Pending", recipientNumber: "0705087633"}, {sort: {paymentDate: 'desc' }}).fetch()
```

Showing:

```
[{…}]
0
:
key : "b21d83ef267bd829a9d732551270c718"
paymentDate : "2018-04-02 15:15:49"
paymentStatus : "Pending"
recipientAmount : "500"
recipientNumber : "0705087633"
_id : "uSsCbdBmmhR2AF2cy"
__proto__ : Object
length : 1
__proto__ : Array(0)
```

It seems like the issue is in the `recipientsDetails.find( connection.data ).fetch();` query. Can someone kindly point out where I am going wrong in my code?

Looking forward to your response.

Comment: rather use proper query in the find() method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you test your `params` include `api_key`. I'm betting this key does not appear in your `recipientsDetails` collection.

Instead of just doing:

```
connection.data.owner = connection.owner;
```

Try:

```
connection.data.owner = connection.owner;
delete connection.data.api_key;
```

Comment: Thanks! Actually the `api_key` does appear in my `recipientsDetails` collection. I did slightly different to what you  suggested and altered the code to `connection.data.owner = connection.data.api_key;`